# Programs to find class number of bi-quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm interested in studying ideal class group structure for bi-quadratic fields.
The problem I'm facing is the lack of examples.
Is there any program where I can find the class number of a bi-quadratic field (at least for small discriminant)?

I've found the following link for real quadratic fields (if it helps someone):
http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnopos.html

Comment: You have already been pointed to sage and magma in other threads. Both of them can do that (and much much more).

Comment: if you want a database, there is QAOS http://qaos.math.tu-berlin.de/qaos/qaos.scm, you can query "d=4 galid=7".